# 2010 Suburban ac blew very hot

Tags: ac, suburban

Unhooked the negative battery cable to reset the check engine light. When it was started after, the ac blew extreme hot. What's up?

Comment: Did it eventually cool off? Did you check fuses? Did you mess with anything else?

Comment: Using a code reader to find out the code may be a good idea...